# If $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j$ is absolutely convergent, and $\sum_{j=1}^\infty b_j$ is conditionally convergent, can $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_jb_j$ diverge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Suppose $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j$ is absolutely convergent, and $\sum_{j=1}^\infty b_j$ is only conditionally convergent. Is it possible for $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_jb_j$ to diverge?

I am trying to come up with a counter example but I am having a hard time.

**Any hints?**

Comment: $\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty b_j$ conditionally convergent implies that $\lim\limits_{j\to\infty}b_j=0$.  In particular, this implies that eventually $|b_j|<1$ from some point onward.  How does $|a_jb_j|$ compare to $|a_j|$ then from that point on?

Answer (score 3):

We must have $b_j \to 0$. Hence there is some $N$ such that $|b_j|<1$ $\forall j \ge N$. But then $|a_j b_j| \le |a_j|$ $\forall j \ge N$ . Then the series $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_jb_j$ is  absolutely convergent.