# How can two convergent series be multiplied to construct a series that diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

One thing to take note is that I am not looking for an example of one case, I am trying to show this in a general form. I understand that this is going to have to involve conditional convergence and proving that series a and b are conditionally convergent, but I don't know where to begin.

Comment: What exactly is the "this" that you are trying to prove?  One example shows that such things exist.

Comment: **Hint:**  The harmonic series is a well known example of a divergent series.  Alternating series however...

Comment: I mean't to say that I need to show a general case of two convergent series being divergent when multiplied.

Comment: Just curious, is this a book problem?

Comment: No, it's just something we learned in class and I struggle when it comes to proving or showing things in general forms.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2476241/if-sum-j-1-infty-a-j-is-absolutely-convergent-and-sum-j-1-infty-b-j?rq=1

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the kind of thing you're looking for, but a general class of examples is given by sequences $a_0 \geqslant a_1 \geqslant \cdots > 0$ such that $a_n \to 0$ and $\sum_na_n$ diverges, because $\sum_n(-1)^n\sqrt{a_n}$ converges.